# Spring MVC @GetMapping("") is executed three times in the first request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've been working with Spring, I don't understand what the problem is. In the **Test.class** Spring MVC controller the code (the default controller, the first request will receive it) in the get request the code is executed three times this method includes 3 threads or 3 get requests.
Synchronized method and `SingleThreadModel` interface don't help, so I think the problem is with three requests?
If I execute the code in a different controller (not in the default fetch request) everything works good.

**Test.class**

```
@Controller
public class Test {

@GetMapping("")
public String hello(ModelMap model) {

       System.out.println("method hello said 'yes'");  //runs twice

       return "index";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">


<display-name>Spring MVC</display-name>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PredictWeather</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:servletsConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PredictWeather</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**servletsConfig.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="servlets"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**logs**
[image: 1]
Perhaps someone has come across, or knows how to solve the problem, thanks for any answer! I ask the question for the first time, perhaps it is poorly formulated

Comment: What is your question here? If the code does not run as you excepted, please state your excepted behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: On every get request, the Code in Test.class is executed 3 times